# accuracy() MAPE output, is the output already in percentage form?

Tags: r, arithmetic

just curious when I get a MAPE of 10.69 from the accuracy function in SDMtools, is the output

10.96% or 1069%. This is really confusing thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While SDMtools has an accuracy function, it does not return a MAPE. Perhaps you mean the accuracy function in the forecast package which does return a MAPE. In that case, MAPE stands for mean absolute percentage error. So yes, the results are percentages.